# Ember waiting for relationships to load in array with ember concurrency

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm attempting to sort an array of model objects based on one of their related models.

I have a **Document** which *hasMany* **LineItem** and a **LineItem** *belongsTo* a **Location**. I want to sort the Line Items by their location. So if I had something like this:

```
let lineItems = [
  {
    itemName: "One",
    location: {
      name: "Kitchen"
    }
  },
  {
    itemName: "Two",
    location: {
      name: "Kitchen"
    }
  },
  {
    itemName: "Three",
    location: {
      name: "Bathroom"
    }
  },
  {
    itemName: "Four",
    location: {
      name: "Bathroom"
    }
  },
  {
    itemName: "Five",
    location: {
      name: "Hall"
    }
  },
  {
    itemName: "Six",
    location: {
      name: "Hall"
    }
  }
];
```

I'd want to get to:

```
let groupedLineItems = {
  "Kitchen": [
    {
      itemName: "One",
      location: "Kitchen"
    },
    {
      itemName: "Two",
      location: "Kitchen"
    },
  ],
  "Bathroom": [
    {
      itemName: "Three",
      location: "Bathroom"
    },
    {
      itemName: "Four",
      location: "Bathroom"
    },
  ],
  "Hall": [
    {
      itemName: "Five",
      location: "Hall"
    },
    {
      itemName: "Six",
      location: "Hall"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've figured out how to sort, but only once all the relationships have loaded. I can't figure out how to use ember concurrency to wait for all the relationships to load before sorting the data.

This is my controller:

```
~/app/controllers/document.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import _ from 'underscore';
import { task } from 'ember-concurrency';
const { computed } = Ember;

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    init() {
        this.get('myTask').perform();
    },

    myTask: task(function * () {
        // Wait for locations to resolve.
        let lineItems = this.get('model').get('lineItems');

        yield this.get("secondTask").perform(lineItems);

        let groupedLineItems = yield _.groupBy(lineItems.toArray(), (lineItem) => {
            lineItem.get('location').then((location) => {
                return location.get('name');
            });
        });

        this.set("groupedLineItems2", Ember.Object.create(groupedLineItems));
    }),

    secondTask: task(function * (lineItems) {
        yield lineItems.toArray().forEach((lineItem) => {
            lineItem.get('location');
        });
    })
});
```

This is WIP on the controller and not correct. On init the first task runs, but doesn't wait for the locations to be loaded for each line item. I'm trying to make it load all the locations in the second task, but is clearly not the right way to do it. Consequently on init it'll run through sorting, but the function for _.groupBy will return undefined because location is undefined at that point. Then if I run the task again manually (using a button on the template) after I know the locations have loaded (because I'm using them elsewhere on the template) it works fine.

Solution doesn't have to use ember concurrency, it just seemed like the right tool, but I think it can be done with promises as well.

Comment: This is not "sorting".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

Here's how I would do it.

`models/document.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Model from "ember-data/model";
import attr from "ember-data/attr";
import { belongsTo, hasMany } from "ember-data/relationships";

export default Model.extend({
  lineItems: hasMany('line-item'),

  groupedLineItemsPromise: Ember.computed(function () {
    return this
      .get('lineItems')
      .then(lineItems => {
        const locations = Ember.RSVP.all(lineItems.map(item => item.get('location')))
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({lineItems, locations})
      })
      .then(({lineItems}) => {
        return lineItems.reduce((result, item) => {
          const locationName = item.get('location.name')
          result[locationName] = result[locationName] || []
          result[locationName].pushObject(item)
          return result
        }, {})
      })
  }),

  groupedLineItemsProxy: Ember.computed('groupedLineItemsPromise', function () {
    return Ember
      .Object
        .extend(Ember.PromiseProxyMixin)
        .create({
        promise: this.get('groupedLineItemsPromise')
      })
  })
});
```

Demo: https://ember-twiddle.com/3f7ee2371c424c456c48347774395191?openFiles=models.document.js%2C

Note that you don't really need `ember-concurrency` for this. I'm using good old computed properties to achieve the result.

But the matter is that this is the wrong approach in the first place, `ember-concurrency` or not:

1. This approach will generate tons of network requests, unless you use the poorly documented feature of grouping network requests (and your backend supports it).
2. In case any of the requests fails, your app will enter an inconsistent state. Probably the whole concurrency task/computed property will fail, and the user will not have a chance to restart the failed request.
3. Your page will render prematurely, with no content. Then the content will eventually appear.

Of course, all three issues can be addressed, but it's a PITA. **The proper way to do it is to preload the relationships in the route's model hook.**

Organize it in such a way that all necessary records are fetched with just a few network requests. Either use JSONAPI filters or make a custom API endpoint that serves all related records.

At worst case, still do a lot of requests, but do it in the route's model hook that will take care of the asynchrony and feed records, not promises, into the controller/template. **Once related records have been preloaded, you can access relationships as if they are synchronous**.

Comment: Thanks, such a good answer!

In the end I realised I needed to do:

`return this.get('store').findRecord('document', params.document_id, { include: 'lineItems.location' });`

In my model hook on the route. Then I could just do:

`groupedLineItems: computed('model.lineItems.@each.location', function() {
        const lineItems = this.get('model').get('lineItems').toArray();
        return this.sortObject(_.groupBy(lineItems, (lineItem) => lineItem.get('location').get('name')));
    })`